# How to use kbd in Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I'd like to be able to show a keyboard button press in Google Docs, but it doesn't appear to have a way to use `<kbd>`, like so: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.

Is there any way to accomplish this in Docs?

If not, what would you suggest I do instead?